# Definite integral involving polylogarithms being slow

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I need to evaluate the following definite integral:

```
Integrate[(3 u^2 (q^3 - Conjugate[q]^3) (1 + q^3 (-2 + u) u + q (s^2 (-1 + u)^2 - (-1 + q^3) (-2 + u) u + 2 t (1 + q^3 (-2 + u) u) + t^2 (-1 - 2 q^3 (-1 + u) u + u^2)) Conjugate[q] + q^2 (1 - 2 s + 2 t + 2 s^2 t - 2 t^2) (-1 + u)^2 Conjugate[q]^2 + ((-2 + u) u + q^3 (-2 + 4 t (-1 + u)^2 - t^2 (-1 + u)^2 - 2 s (-1 + 2 t) (-1 + u)^2 + s^2 (-1 + 2 t) (-1 + u)^2 + 6 u - 3 u^2)) Conjugate[q]^3 + q (-1 + q^3) u (-2 - 2 t (-2 + u) + 2 t^2 (-1 + u) + u) Conjugate[q]^4))/(-1 + q^3 (1 + s t (-1 + u)) u^2 + q (-1 + u) u (1 + s^2 + q^3 t u + q^3 s (-1 + t) t u + t^2 (1 - q^3 u)) Conjugate[q] + q^2 (-1 + u) u (2 + 2 t (-1 + u) - t^2 (-1 + u) + s^2 (1 + (-1 + t)^2 u) + 2 s (-1 + t u)) Conjugate[q]^2 + u^2 (1 - s t + q^3 (-1 - 2 s (-1 + u) + s^2 (2 - 2 t + t^2) (-1 + u)) + s t u) Conjugate[q]^3 + q (-1 + s) (-1 + t) (q^3 (-1 + s) (-1 + t) + t) (-1 + u) u^2 Conjugate[q]^4)^2,{s,0,1},{t,0,1},{u,0,1}]
```

The imaginary part of the result is supposed to be a polylogarithm plus a polynomial which I need. Now it is taking a computer forever to evaluate this integral. May I ask whether I can evaluate it within a reasonable period of time? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the range of values of `q`?

Comment: @dimitris q is a constant complex number that is not real. On the other hand, u,s,t are real. Furthermore I'm only interested in the imaginary part of this integral.